# Keep "this" in bootbox callback functions

Tags: vue.js, bootbox

I'm trying to keep `this` variable in the callback:

```
var that = this

// type1
bootbox.confirm("This is the default confirm!", function(result){ 
    console.log(that.whatever); 
});

// type2
bootbox.confirm({
    message: "This is a confirm with custom button text and color! Do you like it?",
    callback: function (result) {
        console.log(that.whatever);
    }
});
```

It looks ugly, is there any better way to do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 1):

You can use an arrow function:

```
bootbox.confirm("This is the default confirm!", result => { 
    console.log(this.whatever); 
});
```

You should compile this with Babel though, [older browsers may not support it](https://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions). If you have the callback as a variable, you can bind it before passing:

```
yourCb.bind(this);
bootbox.confirm("This is the default confirm!", yourCb);
```

Comment: What about bootbox.confirm({title: XXX, callback: XXX}), do you have a solution for that as well?

Comment: [Bind](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#test-Function.prototype.bind) the `XXX` callback: `XXX.bind(this)` before passing.

Comment: Can you add an example to your answer?

Comment: This is a general JS thing. You control what does the `this` resolve to in a function.